# CMSの見たまま編集機能（ドラッグ＆ドロップするやつ）の仕組みについて

Tags: javascript, php

CMSでたまにあるドラッグ＆ドロップでテキストボックスなどを移動させ、
見たまま編集ができる機能ってどういう仕組みで動作しているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

CMSで割りと使われているのはWYSIWYGですね。

https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors

動きとしては、DOMそのものをJSで動かしたり、contenteditable属性を有効にするなどです。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable